# Caching variables in a custom Hamcrest Matcher

Tags: java, hamcrest

I have created a custom Hamcrest matcher for an interface I'm using.

The matcher is an instance of `TypeSafeMatcher` and it overrides the following three methods:

- `TypeSafeMatcher#matchesSafely(T item)` : `boolean`
- `TypeSafeMatcher#describeMismatchSafely(T item, Description mismatchDescription)` : `void`
- `TypeSafeMatcher#describeTo(Description description)` : `void`

The class I'm matching handles the validation of a certain type of objects. It comes from an external library so I cannot simply change it. Let's call this class `ValidationSubject`

Every instance of `ValidationSubject` this class defines some logic behind the validation to be performed. This is done by implementing `ValidationSubject#validate(ValidationData validationData)` where `validationData` is a builder-type object that allows the programmer to report validation errors based on the state of an object of a class implementing `ValidationSubject`

```
public class Foo implements ValidationSubject {

    private String state;

    private Map<String, Baz> moreState;

    // constructor, methods affecting the state

    // this method is required by ValidationSubject
    @Override
    public void validate(ValidationData validationData) {
        /*
         * call methods on validationData based on the state
         * of the object
         */
    }
}
```

I'm using my matcher to test the validation logic implemented in each concrete class such as `Foo`.

In order to do that, I'd need to stub/mock/spy an instance of `ValidationData` in each test case and see how the state of the `ValidationData` object changed based on the logic performed by the subject under test. That's a lot of boilerplate. I want my matcher to abstract that away

```
assertThat(testedValidationSubject, hasValidationErrors("Illegal character in name", "Description exceeds 200 words", "Age cannot be negative"));
```

In this case, what I'm really matching against the arguments of the `hasValidationErrors` matcher is a set of String values that the subject under test stored in the `ValidationData` object.

Extracting these values takes a bit of code.

```
return new TypeSafeMatcher<ValidationSubject>() {

    @Override
    protected boolean matchesSafely(ValidationSubject item) {
        // this calls the relevant methods on 'item' internally
        Validator validator = new Validator(item);
        List<ValidationMessage> errorMessages = validator.getErrorMessageGroup()
                .getMessages();
        Set<String> actualMessages = errorMessages.stream().map(e -> e.getMessage())
                .collect(Collectors.toSet());
        Set<String> expectedMessages = Stream.of(expectedErrors).collect(Collectors.toSet());
        Set<String> missingMessages = SetUtils.difference(expectedMessages, actualMessages);
        Set<String> unexpectedMessages = SetUtils.difference(actualMessages, expectedMessages);
        return SetUtils.union(unexpectedMessages, missingMessages).isEmpty();
    }

    @Override
    public void describeMismatchSafely(final ValidationSubject item, final Description description) {
                        // this calls the relevant methods on 'item' internally
        Validator validator = new Validator(item);
        List<ValidationMessage> errorMessages = validator.getErrorMessageGroup()
                .getMessages();
        Set<String> actualMessages = errorMessages.stream().map(e -> e.getMessage())
                .collect(Collectors.toSet());
        Set<String> expectedMessages = Stream.of(expectedErrors).collect(Collectors.toSet());
        Set<String> missingMessages = SetUtils.difference(expectedMessages, actualMessages);
        Set<String> unexpectedMessages = SetUtils.difference(actualMessages, expectedMessages);
        description.appendText("Validation errors were missing or unexpected\n")
                .appendValueList("\tSupefluous messages: ", ", ", "\n", unexpectedMessages.toArray())
                .appendValueList("\tMissing messages: ", ", ", "\n", missingMessages.toArray());
    }

    @Override
    public void describeTo(Description description) {
        description.appendText("validation should result in the expected errors");
    }
}
```

This piece of code is repeated line-by-line:

```
Validator validator = new Validator(item);
List<ValidationMessage> errorMessages = validator.getErrorMessageGroup()
        .getMessages();
Set<String> actualMessages = errorMessages.stream().map(e -> e.getMessage())
        .collect(Collectors.toSet());
Set<String> expectedMessages = Stream.of(expectedErrors).collect(Collectors.toSet());
Set<String> missingMessages = SetUtils.difference(expectedMessages, actualMessages);
Set<String> unexpectedMessages = SetUtils.difference(actualMessages, expectedMessages);
```

**I can get rid of the duplication by wrapping this piece in a method or a lambda expression (returning a pair of sets or accepting as a parameter a function to compute the boolean or string I need) but ideally, I'd like to *only execute this once*.**

I need the `item` to figure out the result of both `matchesSafely` and the message output by `describemisMatchSafely` but each time it's passed as a parameter. It's not a parameter of the static method `hasValidationErrors` so I can't see a clean way to cache the result in a couple of variables.

I could potentially execute this code in one of those methods and cache it in a field but [the Javadoc for `TypeSafeMatcher`](http://hamcrest.org/JavaHamcrest/javadoc/1.3/org/hamcrest/TypeSafeMatcher.html) seems to make no guarantees as to which method is executed first.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand what you're trying to do, you're looking for functionality provided by [`TypeSafeDiagnosingMatcher`](http://hamcrest.org/JavaHamcrest/javadoc/1.3/org/hamcrest/TypeSafeDiagnosingMatcher.html). Try extending that instead of `TypeSafeMatcher`:

```
return new TypeSafeDiagnosingMatcher<ValidationSubject>() {

    @Override
    protected boolean matchesSafely(ValidationSubject item, Description mismatchDescription) {
        // this calls the relevant methods on 'item' internally
        Validator validator = new Validator(item);
        List<ValidationMessage> errorMessages = validator.getErrorMessageGroup()
                .getMessages();
        Set<String> actualMessages = errorMessages.stream().map(e -> e.getMessage())
                .collect(Collectors.toSet());
        Set<String> expectedMessages = Stream.of(expectedErrors).collect(Collectors.toSet());
        Set<String> missingMessages = SetUtils.difference(expectedMessages, actualMessages);
        Set<String> unexpectedMessages = SetUtils.difference(actualMessages, expectedMessages);
        mismatchDescription.appendText("Validation errors were missing or unexpected\n")
                .appendValueList("\tSuperfluous messages: ", ", ", "\n", unexpectedMessages.toArray())
                .appendValueList("\tMissing messages: ", ", ", "\n", missingMessages.toArray());
        return SetUtils.union(unexpectedMessages, missingMessages).isEmpty();
    }

    @Override
    public void describeTo(Description description) {
        description.appendText("validation should result in the expected errors");
    }
}
```